# JSON - How to return the location of an error?

Tags: python, json, error-handling

When I try to read a JSON file into Python using Python's built in package [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), I get back a `JSONDecodeError` that looks something like this:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 233451 (char 233450)
```

Is there any way to return the location of the error (in this case, 233450)? What I want is something like:

```
try:
    json.loads(my_json)
except:
    error_loc = json.get_error(my_json)
```

where `error_loc = 233450` - or even just the entire error message as a string, I can extract the number myself.

Context: I'm trying to load some very poorly formatted (webscraped) JSONs into Python. Many of the errors are related to the fact that the text contained in the JSONs contains quotes, curly brackets, and other characters that the json reader interprets as formatting - e.g.

```
{"category": "this text contains "quotes", which messes with the json reader",
"category2": "here's some more text containing "quotes" - and also {brackets}"},
{"category3": "just for fun, here's some text with {"brackets and quotes"} in conjunction"}
```

I managed to eliminate the majority of these situations using regex, but now there's a small handful of cases where I accidentally replaced necessary quotes. Looking through the JSONs manually, I don't actually think it's possible to catch all the bad formatting situations without replacing at least one necessary character. And in almost every situation, the issue is just one missing character, normally towards the very end...

If I could return the location of the error, I could just revert the replaced character and try again.

I feel like there has to be a way to do this, but I don't think I'm using the correct terms to search for it.

Comment: Did you look at the attributes on the error? I see e.g. `lineno`, `colno`, `pos`.

Comment: iterate over the entire string until you get to the 233450th character then see what is there within ~10 characters + or - ?

Comment: Off-topic: You generally shouldn't use "bare" `except:` clauses like that because they can hide unexpected problems from you (like syntax errors) and make debugging more difficult.

Comment: I'd go further than that: a bare `except` should probably be a syntax error, because you want the explicit equivalent (`except BaseException`) so rarely that it's really not worth providing a short cut for it.

Comment: If in this case you used `except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as error:`, you can see what attributes the raised error has via `print(vars(error))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch the error as the variable `error` by `except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as error`. Then, the `JSONDecodeError` object has an attribute `pos`, that gives the index in the string which the JSON decoding error. `lineno` and `colno` can be used to get line number and column number like when opening a file graphically in an editor.

```
try:
    json.loads(string_with_json)
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as error:
    error_pos = error.pos
    error_lineno = error.lineno
    error_colno = error.colno
```